# Assigning value to variable in R with string pattern matching

Tags: r, string, string-matching

I have to detect **Name:** and assign the value to any variable. I am trying to use str_match, but it takes only Sunil

```
x = c("Name: Sunil Raperia ")
xx = str_match(x, "Name: (.*?) ")
xx
```

y = c("Name: 
       Sunil Raperia ")

stringr::str_match(y, "Name: (.*) ")[, 2] is not able to capture the value when the value is in the next line. stringr::str_match(y, "Name: (.*) " /n)[, 2] is not solving it though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str_match` returns a matrix, first column is the complete match whereas 2nd column is the capture group. Since here we want the capture group we can extract the 2nd column.

```
xx <- stringr::str_match(x, "Name: (.*) ")[, 2]
xx
#[1] "Sunil Raperia"
```

However, this can also be done in base R using `sub`

```
sub('Name: ', '', x)
```

OR

```
sub('Name: (.*) ', '\\1', x)
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak, I  am able to solve it, just out of curiosity, [, 2] what is the usage of this one ?

Comment: @SunilRaperia as `str_match` returns a matrix with 2 columns we use `[, 2]` to extract 2nd column.